# Ruyaml: Possible to define line width?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

Is it possible to set YAML line width, when dumping to file with ruyaml?

When dumping a YAML object to file with pyyaml and its content is fairly long 82+(or something similar) characters, there is a row break inserted. This can be circumvented by giving the parameter "width" to the dump function, where you can either give a specific length or as in the example below "inf".

That possibility seems to be missing in ruyaml.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/work/repos/identityhub/bug.py", line 19, in <module>
    ruamel.dump(ruamel_content, ruamel_out.open("w"), width=float("inf"))
TypeError: dump() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'
```

PS. Also added ruamel.yaml example, to verify that it is not an issue in the ruyaml fork.

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruyaml import YAML as RUYAML
from ruamel.yaml import YAML as RUAMEL
import yaml

ruyaml = RUYAML()
ruamel = RUAMEL()
ruyaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)

file_path = Path("test.yaml")
ruyaml_out = Path("ruyaml.yaml")
ruamel_out = Path("ruamel.yaml")
yaml_out = Path("yaml.yaml")

ruyaml_content = ruyaml.load(file_path)
ruyaml.dump(ruyaml_content, ruyaml_out.open("w"))

ruamel_content = ruamel.load(file_path)
ruamel.dump(ruamel_content, ruamel_out.open("w"))

yaml_content = yaml.load(file_path.open())
yaml.dump(yaml_content, yaml_out.open("w"), width=float("inf"))
```

Sample YAML to see the effect:

```
Foo:
  Bar: A very long string A very long string A very long string A very long string A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
yaml = YAML()
yaml.width = 2 ** 32
```

Although `float("inf") > 2` gives `True`, and the `yaml.width` value is currently used for comparison, I cannot guarantee that at some point the internal code needs an actual integer. And since doing `int(float"inf"))`
will give you

```
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

your code would no longer work unless the conversion to int caught that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the "width" member variable on the YAML instance, seems to have the same effect as sending `width=X` to PyYaml dump function.

```
yaml = YAML()
yaml.width = float("inf")
```

Comment: This works great but doesn't pass mypy typechecker:

`error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "int | None")  [assignment]`